# C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code, gcc, Mac: "variable uint32_t is not a type name"

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I've begun using VSC for my embedded C projects with gcc for ARM on a Mac. Having set up include paths in `c_cpp_properties.json`, most of my `#includes` are now working. However, a line such as this:

```
uint32_t m_ttff_seconds = 0;
```

produces a red squiggly underline and the error:

```
variable uint32_t is not a type name
```

The source file in question includes stdint:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and the `includePath` includes:

```
"${HOME}/dev/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include"
```

and:

```
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
```

(the only other option being `msvc-x64`).

The codebase compiles just fine when I use make and gcc. How do I show the C/C++ extension where `uint32_t` is?

Edit:

`stdint.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#if __STDC_HOSTED__
# if defined __cplusplus && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  undef __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  undef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
# endif
# include_next <stdint.h>
#else
# include "stdint-gcc.h"
#endif
#define _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#endif
```

and `stdint-gcc.h` contains:

```
/* 7.8.1.1 Exact-width integer types */

#ifdef __INT8_TYPE__
typedef __INT8_TYPE__ int8_t;
#endif
#ifdef __INT16_TYPE__
typedef __INT16_TYPE__ int16_t;
#endif
#ifdef __INT32_TYPE__
typedef __INT32_TYPE__ int32_t;
#endif
#ifdef __INT64_TYPE__
typedef __INT64_TYPE__ int64_t;
#endif
#ifdef __UINT8_TYPE__
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ uint8_t;
#endif
#ifdef __UINT16_TYPE__
typedef __UINT16_TYPE__ uint16_t;
#endif
#ifdef __UINT32_TYPE__
typedef __UINT32_TYPE__ uint32_t;
#endif
#ifdef __UINT64_TYPE__
typedef __UINT64_TYPE__ uint64_t;
#endif
```

This suggests `__UINT32_TYPE__` is NOT defined when VSC is parsing my code, but it IS defined when I build with make and gcc.

Edit:

Following @mbmcavoy's answer I'm including my `c_cpp_properties.json` file here:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${HOME}/dev/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include",
                "${HOME}/dev/nRF5_SDK_14.0.0_3bcc1f7/components/libraries/util",
                "${HOME}/dev/nRF5_SDK_14.0.0_3bcc1f7/config",
                [many more of these omitted]
                "${HOME}/dev/wisol_SDK_SFM20Rx_master/development/sigfox_cfg2/source",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${HOME}/dev/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include",
                    "${HOME}/dev/nRF5_SDK_14.0.0_3bcc1f7/components/libraries/util",
                    "${HOME}/dev/nRF5_SDK_14.0.0_3bcc1f7/config",
                    [many more of these omitted]
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "databaseFilename": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/browse.vc.db"
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "__UINT_LEAST16_MAX__=65535",
                "__UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__=unsigned char",
                "__UINT8_MAX__=255",
                "__UINT_FAST64_MAX__=18446744073709551615ULL",
                "__UINT_FAST8_MAX__=4294967295U",
                "__UINT_LEAST64_MAX__=18446744073709551615ULL",
                "__UINT_LEAST8_MAX__=255",
                "__UINTMAX_TYPE__=long long unsigned int",
                "__UINT32_MAX__=4294967295UL",
                "__UINT16_C(c)=c",
                "__UINT16_MAX__=65535",
                "__UINT8_TYPE__=unsigned char",
                "__UINT64_C(c)=c ## ULL",
                "__UINT_LEAST16_TYPE__=short unsigned int",
                "__UINT64_MAX__=18446744073709551615ULL",
                "__UINTMAX_C(c)=c ## ULL",
                "__UINT_FAST32_MAX__=4294967295U",
                "__UINT_LEAST64_TYPE__=long long unsigned int",
                "__UINT_FAST16_TYPE__=unsigned int",
                "__UINT_LEAST32_MAX__=4294967295UL",
                "__UINT16_TYPE__=short unsigned int",
                "__UINTPTR_MAX__=4294967295U",
                "__UINT_FAST64_TYPE__=long long unsigned int",
                "__UINT_LEAST32_TYPE__=long unsigned int",
                "__UINT8_C(c)=c",
                "__UINT64_TYPE__=long long unsigned int",
                "__UINT32_C(c)=c ## UL",
                "__UINT_FAST32_TYPE__=unsigned int",
                "__UINTMAX_MAX__=18446744073709551615ULL",
                "__UINT32_TYPE__=long unsigned int",
                "__UINTPTR_TYPE__=unsigned int",
                "__UINT_FAST16_MAX__=4294967295U",
                "__UINT_FAST8_TYPE__=unsigned int"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```

Edit:

On digging deeper, I found that `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/include/stdint.h` had `__STDC_HOSTED__` defined and therefore `stdint-gcc.h` was not actually being included. Instead, that header does an "`include_next <stdint.h>`", which finds `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/arm-none-eabi/include/stdint.h`. I still can't see where unint32_t is defined, either for gcc and make or for VSC.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: C. Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Could you be missing something after ".../include" in the path?

Comment: No, that's where stdint.h and stdint-gcc.h are.

Comment: Not sure whats going on, but you could work around the limitation using typedef instead

Comment: I think the issue is that you're trying to use a Microsoft product on a non-Microsoft platform. There are tons of editors/IDEs that integrate so much better with the tools you're using than this abomination that is VS Code.

Comment: @rubenvb Such as? And don't you dare say Eclipse.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, except I am actually running Visual Studio Code on Windows. By running `arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E -`, I can see that GCC defines many of these by default: `#define __UINT32_TYPE__ long unsigned int`, etc. I'm not sure how to pre-populate that define for VSCode. If I add it to the c_cpp_properties.json includes, it ends up as `long unsigned int 1`, and doesn't work right.

Comment: I have added `"__UINT32_TYPE__=long unsigned int"` to the `defines` section of c_cpp_properties.json. Now, in the stdint-gcc.h typedef line, if I hover over `__UINT32_TYPE__`,  the tooltip shows `#define __UINT32_TYPE__ long unsigned int`. This matches the define in the compiler. However, if I hover over `uint32_t`, the tooltip is `typedef unsigned long uint32_t` which does not seem correct. Also, it still shows the orignial error message that uint32_t is not a type name...

Comment: Are you looking for file like this https://github.com/deleisha/libuv/blob/v1.x/include/stdint-msvc2008.h .

Comment: @dlmeetei Not really, sorry. I'm not using a Microsoft compiler, as should be clear from the question.

Comment: The update c_cpp_properties.json file has all the __UINT* stuff, but there should be more. Does arm-none-eabi-gcc define __STDC_HOSTED__?

Comment: `I still can't see where unint32_t is defined, either for gcc and make or for VSC` - Debug tip: let the compiler tell you by forcing a name collision error by declaring a variable with the same name, e.g. `int uint32_t;`. Then gcc will complain `‘uint32_t’ redeclared as different kind of symbol` and most importantly inform that `/usr/include/bits/stdint-uintn.h:26:20: note: previous declaration of ‘uint32_t’ was here`.

Answer (score 3):

After trying all of the proposed solutions to no effect, I consider the uint32_t  issue to be a bug.

To solve the annoying warnings in VSCode, just add the following line after your #include section:

```
typedef __uint32_t uint32_t;
```

By doing this once in a single file, it fixes my VSCode warnings and still compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this on my machine (Windows), with three steps:

1. Applying Compiler Defines to the C/C++ Extension

The question is correct when it states "This suggests `__UINT32_TYPE__` is NOT defined when VSC is parsing my code, but it IS defined when I build with make and gcc." The ARM cross-compiler has many built-in defines that are not included in the clang-x64 parser.

First, find out defines your gcc compiler defines, with the `-dM -E` options. On Windows I was able to dump the output to a file with `echo | arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E - > gcc-defines.txt`

```
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __HQ_FBIT__ 15
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __SFRACT_IBIT__ 0
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.1754943508222875e-38F
#define __GCC_IEC_559_COMPLEX 0
(etc. - I have 344 defines)
```

Second, add the defines to your `c_cpp_properties.json` file. Note that where the #define sets a value, you need to use an `=` sign here. (You could probably just add individual defines as you need them, but I used Excel to format them as needed and sort. The first defines are for my project, matching the defines in my Makefile.)

```
"defines": [
    "STM32F415xx",
    "USE_FULL_LL_DRIVER",
    "__USES_INITFINI__",
    "__ACCUM_EPSILON__=0x1P-15K",
    "__ACCUM_FBIT__=15",
    (...)
    "__UINT32_TYPE__=long unsigned int",
    (etc.)
```

2. Setting the Symbol Database

After doing a few experiments with individual defines, I could see the define as being processed in `stdint-gcc.h`, any uses of the types still produced errors. I realized in my `c_cpp_properties.json` file that I had `"databaseFilename": ""` This is used for the "generated symbol database", but was not configured properly. I set it to:

```
"databaseFilename": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/browse.vc.db"
```

3. Restart Visual Studio Code

After quitting and restarting Visual Studio Code, declarations do not result in the error, and when hovering over a variable, it shows the appropriate type.

Comment: It should be defined regardless. At least since VS10, the C/C++ compiler (`cl.exe`) knows what `stdint.h` is and what `uint32_t` is without more.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is no the same as Visual Studio, and does not include a compiler or headers. If Visual Studio is also installed, it can make use of them, but when developing for an embedded ARM processor, these are the wrong compiler and headers to use. The reference to `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is for the GNU ARM Toolchain. The parser in Visual Studio Code must to told where to find those headers, and also the built-in defines that are used by that compiler.

Comment: In the question, @eliot had changed the include path so that the VSCode parser was finding the correct ARM headers. However, without at least some of the defines, the headers were not processed correctly, leaving `uint32_t` incorrectly defined. Note that he is also on a Mac, which won't have the Microsoft compiler available, although by default it appears that the default points to where the equivalent system headers should be located.

Comment: @mbmcavoy Thanks for the awesome detail, but I've followed this pretty closely and still see the errors on uint32_t. I'm only using a subset of the defines, but I think I have all the UNIT stuff covered. Any ideas?

Comment: @eliot I thought when I first did it that I had manually just put in the ones I needed and it worked, but I was retracing my steps for a full writeup, and found that it did not. The intermediate headers (stdint.h x2 etc.) have many `#ifdef` directives, so I think it's not even getting to the stdint-gcc.h without them. Tracking down each one and entering it manually would be possible, but easy to load them all: Dump to file; remove the leading "#define "; if there are spaces, replace the first with an equals sign; paste into the settings.

Comment: @mbmcavoy Thanks again. I loaded the whole lot and still had the issue, so began to dig deeper - details above in an edit. Could be that what you did works for Windows and not for Mac, I don't know.