# uint32_t does not name a type - VSCode with STM32 in Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, stm32, uint32

I am currently writing code for a project, specifically interfacing with sensors via an STM32 Nucleo F411RE board. I set the pins/peripherals etc. using STM32CubeMX, then generated the code with the Makefile toolchain for programming in  Visual Studio Code. Everything is compiling fine, but the IDE/Intellisense for some reason doesn't pick up any use of `uint32_t`; any occurences are red-squiggled, with the error reading `variable "uint32_t" is not a type name`.

I have `#include <stdint.h>` at the top, and `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` are both recognized in the same file. Peeking the definition of those reveals their lines in `stdint.h`, while the same does not work for `uint32_t`. I have attempted the solutions suggested [here](http://shadetail.com/blog/using-visual-studio-code-for-arm-development-defines/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701187/c-c-extension-for-visual-studio-code-gcc-mac-variable-uint32-t-is-not-a-ty?r=SearchResults), neither of which worked.

I am working in C11 (not c++, which isn't an option for my project) on Windows, here is my `c_cpp_properties.json` file (with all the extra defines cut out for compactness):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "databaseFilename": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/browse.vc.db",
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Here is `<stdint.h>` - all types are clearly declared together, with no apparent condition for uint32_t:

```
#pragma once
#define _STDINT

#ifndef RC_INVOKED

#include <vcruntime.h>



typedef signed char        int8_t;
typedef short              int16_t;
typedef int                int32_t;
typedef long long          int64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

typedef signed char        int_least8_t;
typedef short              int_least16_t;
typedef int                int_least32_t;
typedef long long          int_least64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint_least8_t;
typedef unsigned short     uint_least16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint_least32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint_least64_t;

typedef signed char        int_fast8_t;
typedef int                int_fast16_t;
typedef int                int_fast32_t;
typedef long long          int_fast64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint_fast8_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint_fast64_t;

typedef long long          intmax_t;
typedef unsigned long long uintmax_t;

// These macros must exactly match those in the Windows SDK's intsafe.h.
#define INT8_MIN         (-127i8 - 1)
#define INT16_MIN        (-32767i16 - 1)
#define INT32_MIN        (-2147483647i32 - 1)
#define INT64_MIN        (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)
#define INT8_MAX         127i8
#define INT16_MAX        32767i16
#define INT32_MAX        2147483647i32
#define INT64_MAX        9223372036854775807i64
#define UINT8_MAX        0xffui8
#define UINT16_MAX       0xffffui16
#define UINT32_MAX       0xffffffffui32
#define UINT64_MAX       0xffffffffffffffffui64

#define INT_LEAST8_MIN   INT8_MIN
#define INT_LEAST16_MIN  INT16_MIN
#define INT_LEAST32_MIN  INT32_MIN
#define INT_LEAST64_MIN  INT64_MIN
#define INT_LEAST8_MAX   INT8_MAX
#define INT_LEAST16_MAX  INT16_MAX
#define INT_LEAST32_MAX  INT32_MAX
#define INT_LEAST64_MAX  INT64_MAX
#define UINT_LEAST8_MAX  UINT8_MAX
#define UINT_LEAST16_MAX UINT16_MAX
#define UINT_LEAST32_MAX UINT32_MAX
#define UINT_LEAST64_MAX UINT64_MAX

#define INT_FAST8_MIN    INT8_MIN
#define INT_FAST16_MIN   INT32_MIN
#define INT_FAST32_MIN   INT32_MIN
#define INT_FAST64_MIN   INT64_MIN
#define INT_FAST8_MAX    INT8_MAX
#define INT_FAST16_MAX   INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST32_MAX   INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST64_MAX   INT64_MAX
#define UINT_FAST8_MAX   UINT8_MAX
#define UINT_FAST16_MAX  UINT32_MAX
#define UINT_FAST32_MAX  UINT32_MAX
#define UINT_FAST64_MAX  UINT64_MAX

#ifdef _WIN64
    #define INTPTR_MIN   INT64_MIN
    #define INTPTR_MAX   INT64_MAX
    #define UINTPTR_MAX  UINT64_MAX
#else
    #define INTPTR_MIN   INT32_MIN
    #define INTPTR_MAX   INT32_MAX
    #define UINTPTR_MAX  UINT32_MAX
#endif

#define INTMAX_MIN       INT64_MIN
#define INTMAX_MAX       INT64_MAX
#define UINTMAX_MAX      UINT64_MAX

#define PTRDIFF_MIN      INTPTR_MIN
#define PTRDIFF_MAX      INTPTR_MAX

#ifndef SIZE_MAX
    #define SIZE_MAX     UINTPTR_MAX
#endif

#define SIG_ATOMIC_MIN   INT32_MIN
#define SIG_ATOMIC_MAX   INT32_MAX

#define WCHAR_MIN        0x0000
#define WCHAR_MAX        0xffff

#define WINT_MIN         0x0000
#define WINT_MAX         0xffff

#define INT8_C(x)    (x)
#define INT16_C(x)   (x)
#define INT32_C(x)   (x)
#define INT64_C(x)   (x ## LL)

#define UINT8_C(x)   (x)
#define UINT16_C(x)  (x)
#define UINT32_C(x)  (x ## U)
#define UINT64_C(x)  (x ## ULL)

#define INTMAX_C(x)  INT64_C(x)
#define UINTMAX_C(x) UINT64_C(x)



#endif // RC_INVOKED

/*
* Copyright (c) 1992-2012 by P.J. Plauger.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
* Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.00:0009 */
```

Both `uint_fast16_t` and `uint_fast32_t` have no problems when I use them, which rules out type being an issue - they are both `unsigned int`, the same as `uint32_t`.

EDIT: While making an MCVE, I narrowed the problem down to `#include`-ing `"stm32f4xx_hal.h"` - without this `#include`, a `uint32_t` declares fine. Here is a file that demonstrates the problem (changing the order of the includes does not make a difference):

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

#define MA302_READ_MASK 0x4000
#define MA302_WRITE_MASK 0x8000
#define MA302_ADDRESS_MASK 0x1F
#define MA302_READ_BLANK_VALUE 0x0000

typedef struct {
    uint32_t tester; // 'variable "uint32_t" is not a type name"'
    uint16_t current_raw_16; // declares fine
    uint8_t current_raw_8; // declares fine
    float current_angle;
} ma302gq_p_t;

uint8_t ma302_read_register(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hndlr, uint8_t address);
float ma302_get_angle(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hndlr);
float ma302_raw_to_degrees(uint8_t raw_bit_size, uint16_t raw_angle);
void ma302_init(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hndlr);
```

`"stm32f4xx_hal.h"` is part of the code generated by STM32CubeMX, and itself `#include`s `"stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h"`. Adding `#include <stdint.h>` to `"stm32f4xx_hal.h"` allows `uint32_t`s to temporarily declare in that file; however, switching to the above file and back in VSCode causes the declaration to glitch, and when hovered over, show `<error-type> uint32_t`

EDIT 2:
Here is the first problem file; I didn't include it before as it is automatically generated.
`"stm32f4xx_hal.h"`:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32f4xx_hal.h
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @brief   This file contains all the functions prototypes for the HAL 
  *          module driver.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2017 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */ 

/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __STM32F4xx_HAL_H
#define __STM32F4xx_HAL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h"

/** @addtogroup STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup HAL
  * @{
  */ 

/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/

/** @defgroup HAL_Exported_Constants HAL Exported Constants
  * @{
  */

/** @defgroup HAL_TICK_FREQ Tick Frequency
  * @{
  */
typedef enum
{
  HAL_TICK_FREQ_10HZ         = 100U,
  HAL_TICK_FREQ_100HZ        = 10U,
  HAL_TICK_FREQ_1KHZ         = 1U,
  HAL_TICK_FREQ_DEFAULT      = HAL_TICK_FREQ_1KHZ
} HAL_TickFreqTypeDef;
/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** @defgroup HAL_Exported_Macros HAL Exported Macros
  * @{
  */

/** @brief  Freeze/Unfreeze Peripherals in Debug mode 
  */
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM2()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM2_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM3()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM3_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM4()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM4_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM5()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM5_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM6()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM6_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM7()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM7_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM12()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM12_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM13()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM13_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM14()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM14_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_RTC()            (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_RTC_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_WWDG()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_WWDG_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_IWDG()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_IWDG_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_I2C1_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C1_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_I2C2_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C2_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_I2C3_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C3_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_CAN1()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_CAN1_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_CAN2()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_CAN2_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM1()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM1_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM8()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM8_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM9()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM9_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM10()          (DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM10_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_FREEZE_TIM11()          (DBGMCU->APB2FZ |= (DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM11_STOP))

#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM2()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM2_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM3()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM3_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM4()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM4_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM5()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM5_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM6()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM6_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM7()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM7_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM12()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM12_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM13()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM13_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM14()          (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_TIM14_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_RTC()            (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_RTC_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_WWDG()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_WWDG_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_IWDG()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_IWDG_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_I2C1_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C1_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_I2C2_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C2_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_I2C3_TIMEOUT()   (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_I2C3_SMBUS_TIMEOUT))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_CAN1()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_CAN1_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_CAN2()           (DBGMCU->APB1FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB1_FZ_DBG_CAN2_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM1()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM1_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM8()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM8_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM9()           (DBGMCU->APB2FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM9_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM10()          (DBGMCU->APB2FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM10_STOP))
#define __HAL_DBGMCU_UNFREEZE_TIM11()          (DBGMCU->APB2FZ &= ~(DBGMCU_APB2_FZ_DBG_TIM11_STOP))

/** @brief  Main Flash memory mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_FLASH()             (SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE))

/** @brief  System Flash memory mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_SYSTEMFLASH()       do {SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE);\
                                                        SYSCFG->MEMRMP |= SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_0;\
                                                        }while(0);

/** @brief  Embedded SRAM mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_SRAM()       do {SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE);\
                                                  SYSCFG->MEMRMP |= (SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_0 | SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_1);\
                                                }while(0);

#if defined(STM32F405xx) || defined(STM32F415xx) || defined(STM32F407xx)|| defined(STM32F417xx)
/** @brief  FSMC Bank1 (NOR/PSRAM 1 and 2) mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_FSMC()       do {SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE);\
                                                  SYSCFG->MEMRMP |= (SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_1);\
                                                }while(0);
#endif /* STM32F405xx || STM32F415xx || STM32F407xx || STM32F417xx */

#if defined(STM32F427xx) || defined(STM32F437xx) || defined(STM32F429xx)|| defined(STM32F439xx) ||\
    defined(STM32F469xx) || defined(STM32F479xx)
/** @brief  FMC Bank1 (NOR/PSRAM 1 and 2) mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_FMC()       do {SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE);\
                                                SYSCFG->MEMRMP |= (SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_1);\
                                                }while(0);

/** @brief  FMC/SDRAM Bank 1 and 2 mapped at 0x00000000
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_FMC_SDRAM()       do {SYSCFG->MEMRMP &= ~(SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE);\
                                                      SYSCFG->MEMRMP |= (SYSCFG_MEMRMP_MEM_MODE_2);\
                                                      }while(0);
#endif /* STM32F427xx || STM32F437xx || STM32F429xx || STM32F439xx || STM32F469xx || STM32F479xx */ 

#if defined(STM32F410Tx) || defined(STM32F410Cx) || defined(STM32F410Rx) || defined(STM32F413xx) || defined(STM32F423xx)
/** @defgroup Cortex_Lockup_Enable Cortex Lockup Enable
  * @{
  */
/** @brief  SYSCFG Break Lockup lock
  *         Enables and locks the connection of Cortex-M4 LOCKUP (Hardfault) output to TIM1/8 input
  * @note   The selected configuration is locked and can be unlocked by system reset
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_BREAK_PVD_LOCK()      do {SYSCFG->CFGR2 &= ~(SYSCFG_CFGR2_PVD_LOCK); \
                                              SYSCFG->CFGR2 |= SYSCFG_CFGR2_PVD_LOCK;    \
                                              }while(0)
/**
 * @}
 */

/** @defgroup PVD_Lock_Enable PVD Lock
  * @{
  */
/** @brief  SYSCFG Break PVD lock
  *         Enables and locks the PVD connection with Timer1/8 Break Input, , as well as the PVDE and PLS[2:0] in the PWR_CR register
  * @note   The selected configuration is locked and can be unlocked by system reset
  */
#define __HAL_SYSCFG_BREAK_LOCKUP_LOCK()     do {SYSCFG->CFGR2 &= ~(SYSCFG_CFGR2_LOCKUP_LOCK); \
                                                SYSCFG->CFGR2 |= SYSCFG_CFGR2_LOCKUP_LOCK;    \
                                                }while(0)
/**
 * @}
 */
#endif /* STM32F410Tx || STM32F410Cx || STM32F410Rx || STM32F413xx || STM32F423xx */
/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup HAL_Private_Macros HAL Private Macros
  * @{
  */
#define IS_TICKFREQ(FREQ) (((FREQ) == HAL_TICK_FREQ_10HZ)  || \
                          ((FREQ) == HAL_TICK_FREQ_100HZ) || \
                          ((FREQ) == HAL_TICK_FREQ_1KHZ))
/**
  * @}
  */

/* Exported functions --------------------------------------------------------*/
/** @addtogroup HAL_Exported_Functions
  * @{
  */
/** @addtogroup HAL_Exported_Functions_Group1
  * @{
  */
/* Initialization and Configuration functions  ******************************/
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_Init(void);
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_DeInit(void);
void HAL_MspInit(void);
void HAL_MspDeInit(void);
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_InitTick (uint32_t TickPriority);
/**
  * @}
  */

/** @addtogroup HAL_Exported_Functions_Group2
  * @{
  */
/* Peripheral Control functions  ************************************************/
void HAL_IncTick(void);
void HAL_Delay(uint32_t Delay);
uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void);
uint32_t HAL_GetTickPrio(void);
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SetTickFreq(HAL_TickFreqTypeDef Freq);
HAL_TickFreqTypeDef HAL_GetTickFreq(void);
void HAL_SuspendTick(void);
void HAL_ResumeTick(void);
uint32_t HAL_GetHalVersion(void);
uint32_t HAL_GetREVID(void);
uint32_t HAL_GetDEVID(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGSleepMode(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_DisableDBGSleepMode(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGStopMode(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_DisableDBGStopMode(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGStandbyMode(void);
void HAL_DBGMCU_DisableDBGStandbyMode(void);
void HAL_EnableCompensationCell(void);
void HAL_DisableCompensationCell(void);
void HAL_GetUID(uint32_t *UID);
#if defined(STM32F427xx) || defined(STM32F437xx) || defined(STM32F429xx)|| defined(STM32F439xx) ||\
    defined(STM32F469xx) || defined(STM32F479xx)
void HAL_EnableMemorySwappingBank(void);
void HAL_DisableMemorySwappingBank(void);
#endif /* STM32F427xx || STM32F437xx || STM32F429xx || STM32F439xx || STM32F469xx || STM32F479xx */ 
/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */
/* Private types -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/** @defgroup HAL_Private_Variables HAL Private Variables
  * @{
  */
/**
  * @}
  */
/* Private constants ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/** @defgroup HAL_Private_Constants HAL Private Constants
  * @{
  */
/**
  * @}
  */
/* Private macros ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */ 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __STM32F4xx_HAL_H */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

STM has a huge web of files all `#include`-ing each other, there's only so much I can put in one post. Anyone with STM32CubeMX and VSCode should be able to replicate this.

Comment: If you already have looked in the `<stdint.h>` header file for the `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` types, why not keep reading the file to see if you can find out under what conditions the `uint32_t` type is defined?

Comment: There don't appear to be any conditions; all `uint` types are simply `typedef`-ed unconditionally in `<stdint.h>`. Some posts referenced some things that needed to be `#defined`-ed, as in the solutions I mentioned, but adding these made no difference.

Comment: Does Microsoft's c compiler even support c11? Does it support embedded ARM targets?

Comment: As I mentioned, the program compiles fine; the problem is to do with the IDE or Intellisense somehow.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I won't be surprised if there were some preprocessor definition somewhere overriding uint32_t.

Comment: Since the problem only occurs when the header file: `stm32f4xx_hal.h` is included, so we need to see the contents of that file

Answer (score 9):

The `stm32f4xx_hal.h` header will mess with your `stdint.h` types if you have not defined your MCU in the vscode workspace. In `c_cpp_properties.json`, make sure you include:

```
"defines": [
    "STM32F411xx", // (or whatever your makefile defines)
    (...)
],
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent ages and I could not figure out what was causing the problem. This solved my problem 100%.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This solved my problem in 15 seconds.

Comment: How do I determine what my generic device name is?  I'm using a STM32L476QEI6TR, and I see references to `STM32L4xx_HAL_H`, so I'm assuming `STM32L4xx` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can check MCU GCC Compiler settings in Cube IDE under Project Properties menu in c/c++ build section. Look for the "gcc" command option, it contains actual mcu name as parameter. Another way to catch it is from verbose build output menu.  Or just create empty Cube MX project for the same MCU and generate makefile that will eventually contain the name.

Answer (score 6):

New answer from [vscode-cpptools issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1212). The same problem as mentioned by @vxhht: some STM32 library mass up the `stdint.h`. But it is not caused by missing MCU definition:

> It's not a bug -- in `core_cm3.h`, it needs to have a compiler define set, such as `__CC_ARM` or it hits a "#error Unknown compiler".

So add `__CC_ARM` to `defines` section of `c_cpp_properties.json` solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

all you need to do is:

1. define your microcontroller
2. define USE_HAL_DRIVER
3. define your compiler __CC_ARM

in cpp_properties.json file
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Oddly uint8_t and unit16_t types for declarations in Visual Studio 2019 C++14 are fine, but uint32_t is not.  All these types are fine for IAR compiler cross compiled for STM32F413.  But goal is to unit test the target code with Boost Test on Visual Studio C++.  Preprocessor symbol STM32F413xx was added to Visual Studio project but did not improve situation.
It is true comment out the stm32f4*.h and #include <stdint.h> is fine for uint32_t
but must have the stm32f4*.h headers to BoostTest target code though #ifdef out hardware accesses.  Previous answer does not say how stm32f4xx_hal.h messes with uint32_t.