# Use VSCode to compile and run STM32 projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32

I been using Visual Studio and VSCode for a long time; therefore, it will be great if I can use it instead of Eclipse or [Keil](https://www.keil.com/). Should I move to those IDEs? **I like having no dependencies where I have a make file that compiles and flashes my code to an stm32.** Moreover, I can customize VSCode a lot. For example I have a plugin called highlight and I have a regex that will highlight everything that is between `USER CODE BEGIN` and `USER CODE END`. As a result my code looks like this:
[image]

Now I know that my code can only exist on the highlighted regions. That way if I make any changes using CubeMx my code will not be lost.

Thanks to this videos I am able to debug, compile and flash stm32 projects:

- Part 1: https://youtu.be/PxQw5_7yI8Q
- Part 2: https://youtu.be/PxQw5_7yI8Q

> For some reason I had to create a `build` directory at the root of my project for my make file to run.

### **Anyways my question is how can I remove the squiggles on VSCode? It will be great if VSCode gave me no errors/warnings**

For example I get a lot of squiggles on the `SystemCLock_Config` function:
[image]

But that is strange because if I press F12 on the `__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG` function it takes me to `...MyProject\Drivers\STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver\Inc\stm32l1xx_hal_pwr.h` and the definition is `#define __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(__REGULATOR__) (MODIFY_REG(PWR->CR, PWR_CR_VOS, (__REGULATOR__)))`

So for some reason F12 is able to find the definition but not the compiler. A solution would be to place this at the top of my main.c file:

```
#ifdefine _DEBUG
#define PWR 0
#endif
```

But it is tedious to do that for every squiggly error.

This question from stack-overflow has help me remove some errors but not all:
[uint32_t does not name a type - VSCode with STM32 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713543/uint32-t-does-not-name-a-type-vscode-with-stm32-in-windows).

Anyways from doing research from the internet this is how my c_cpp_properties.json file looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "STM32 L1",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "DUSE_HAL_DRIVER",
                "DSTM32L152xE",
                "STM32L1xx",
                "__CC_ARM"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm",            
            "compilerPath": "${env:ARMGCC_DIR}/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-mcpu=cortex-m3",
                "-mthumb"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I am using this board: https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l152re.html . I have also tried it with the bluepill and I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

This file `...MyProject\Drivers\CMSIS\Device\ST\STM32L1xx\Include\stm32l1xx.h`

Has this code

```cpp
//.....
#if defined(STM32L100xB)
  #include "stm32l100xb.h"
#elif defined(STM32L100xBA)
  #include "stm32l100xba.h"
#elif defined(STM32L100xC)
  #include "stm32l100xc.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xB)
  #include "stm32l151xb.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xBA)
  #include "stm32l151xba.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xC)
  #include "stm32l151xc.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xCA)
  #include "stm32l151xca.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xD)
  #include "stm32l151xd.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xDX)
  #include "stm32l151xdx.h"
#elif defined(STM32L151xE)
  #include "stm32l151xe.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xB)
  #include "stm32l152xb.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xBA)
  #include "stm32l152xba.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xC)
  #include "stm32l152xc.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xCA)
  #include "stm32l152xca.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xD)
  #include "stm32l152xd.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xDX)
  #include "stm32l152xdx.h"
#elif defined(STM32L152xE)
  #include "stm32l152xe.h"
#elif defined(STM32L162xC)
  #include "stm32l162xc.h"
#elif defined(STM32L162xCA)
  #include "stm32l162xca.h"
#elif defined(STM32L162xD)
  #include "stm32l162xd.h"
#elif defined(STM32L162xDX)
  #include "stm32l162xdx.h"
#elif defined(STM32L162xE)
  #include "stm32l162xe.h"
#else
 #error "Please select first the target STM32L1xx device used in your application (in stm32l1xx.h file)"
#endif
```

So I had to add the definition STM32L152xE on my `c_cpp_properties.json` file. My c_cpp_properties.json file contains this:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "DUSE_HAL_DRIVER",
                "DSTM32L152xE",
                "STM32L152xE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "${env:ARMGCC_DIR}/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-mcpu=cortex-m3",
                "-mthumb"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: I believe you just needed to remove the D in front of "DSTM32L152xE"