# C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code "variable "u8"" is not a type name”

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for embedded C projects with the C/C++ extention from Microsoft. I have a given type naming scheme that I am not in charge of and can not change anything about.

To use those names I have for example these following `typedefs`

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef signed char s8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef volatile unsigned long vu32;
```

When using the `u8` type anywhere (even in the line after the typedef) it **does not get highlighted** as a typename while it **does get highlited in the typedef line** itself. It gets **marked as en error** with this error message:

```
"Variable "u8"" is not a type name.
```

All the other types work just fine.

It seems not to be a problem of the lenght since the `s8` type works. I tried to change it to `u7` and that works so it should not be the "u" in the beginning and I tried to add a letter like so: `u8e`, that worked as well.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701187/c-c-extension-for-visual-studio-code-gcc-mac-variable-uint32-t-is-not-a-ty) and when I try this four liner on its own:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short u16;
u8 testVar8;
u16 testVar16;
```

I do not get the error so starts to confuse me even more.

While writing this question I went back to the VS Code window just to notice all the red underscores had disapperd together with all the errors but the next when I open VS Code I had the same issue.

Comment: You have a VS Code problem, not a C/C++ problem. There is nothing wrong with your typedefs, so I suspect that you have an issue above the typedef lines that is throwing syntax highlighting off.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin u8 is id for standard string literal, he invokes UB, kind of.

Comment: Well yes and no. The `u8` literal specifier is similar to the `U` or `UL` suffix for numeric values, it isn't a lvalue issue and does not impact typedef tag space. [C11 Standard - 6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5)

Comment: After playing around und changing everything to fixed length stdint.h confom types it turns out that vs code semms to have a completly different issue since it does not like uint8_t either. It might have to do something with typedef bitstructs using that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will still compile. It's just that from C11, `u8` followed by a quoted string means that the following string is encoded in UTF-8. There are others too: `U` and `L` are particularly pernicious as you can see them being used as upper and lower in optimisation code, particularly that converted from FORTRAN. This is *not* a breaking change in the language by the way.

The only real issue here is that the syntax highlighter in MSVC uses a different toolset to the actual compiler and, though it's an impressive piece of kit, it's not perfect.

Personally I'd change your typedefs to

```
typedef uint16_t u16;
typedef volatile unsigned long uint32_t vu32;
```

with a view to removing all of them entirely (yes I know that's not an option currently but one of your jobs as a programmer is to influence). Currently the final `typedef` will need to be adjusted to work correctly on typical Unix toolsets.

Comment: u8 is C11 which gets funny because some toolsets support them prior or without support for C11 . :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Typo; honest?

Answer (score 1):

In ISO C standard and in VS `u8` is one of [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), but you gain access to them through a header, possibly `locale.h` included through `string`. MS document on those  is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019).

It's not recommended to use such short ids , also you'd be better off by  define types through [fixed length types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: As is stated I am not the one to deside what ids to use (sadly) and the compiler I have to use (again sadly) does not know fixed lenght types. But since I can't tell VS to ignore the string literals (correct me if I'm wrong) I guess I have to rename it and rename it beck before commiting. Thank you though you lifted up the magic vail.

Comment: Do you have an idea why the minimal example works though?

Comment: Technically there is no prohibition in the standard for use of `u8` or any other valid identifier as a typedef. All `u8` does is specify what the string-literal behind it contains [C11 Standard - 6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) It is an `"encoding prefix"`.

Comment: @EN20 which compler?  those are actually predating C11 standard, you need proper include. Most embedded compilers I know actually have such. Minimal example work, because it got minimal set of includes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin with implementation of user-defined literals in C++ compilers things get funny for static code analyzers.

Comment: Its the COSMIC compiler and I do not have any includes in the file with the typedefs either. Again today after letting IntelliSence stare at the code for an houre or so the errors disapear. I guess it might just really be due to the string literal that throws off the tokaniser